# Резиновый сайт

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Привет! Хочу спросить: как сделать резиновый сайт? Задать в процентах width. Сделала. 
Но... Все таки не получается. Пожалуйста, поподробнее подскажите кто-нибудь.

Comment: нынче популярно делать сайты из 3 колонок, причем ширина центральной  указывается явно а у боковых ширина резиновая. контент размещается только в центральной, а две по краям пустые, - что позволяет сайту одинаково выглядеть на обычном монике и wide-screen. К тому же ширина центральной выбирается под самые распостраненные расширания, напр: 1024
наглядным примером является этот сайт.

Answer (score 2):

Есть ресурс htmlbook.ru на нём есть замечательные готовые макеты с пояснения. Можете ознакомиться здесь - [Макеты](http://htmlbook.ru/layout)

Answer (score 0):

Задаешь width для body или html в 100% и дальше все относительно этого указываешь в процентах. И еще, чистое ИМХО, резиновые сайты выглядят убого, особенно на мониторах 20"-24", лучше все таки делать ограниченные, но тут зависит от самого сайта еще.